# How to derive the equilibrium length of a spring?

Tags: classical-mechanics

A straight wire rotates with constant angular speed $\omega$ about one of its end points (the origin $O$) in a horizontal plane containing $e_1$ and $e_2$. A bead of mass $m$ is free to slide along the wire, but is connected to $O$ by a spring coiled around the wire, as illustrated below. The spring has natural length $a$ and spring constant $k$. The magnitude of the frictional force is proportional to the radial speed of the bead with a frictional constant $K$.

[image]

Assuming $\omega\neq\omega_s$, find the equilibrium length of the spring, say $R$.

I have worked through previous parts of the question and have derived the equation of motion of the bead which is $$\ddot{r}+\alpha\dot{r}=(\omega^2-\omega_s^2)r+a\omega_s^2,$$ where $\alpha=\frac{K}{m}$ and $\omega_s^2=\frac{k}{m}$.

But I struggle on how to derive the equilibrium length of the spring, I don't know how to start.

Thank you.

Comment: The spring has to be extended far enough from its natural length to provide the right amount of centripetal force to maintain the mass at a constant radius.

Comment: @amd So, I take the sum of all the applied forces on the particle to be equal to zero?

Comment: Pretty much. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bead is free to slide on the wire and we’re not given any information about static friction, so if the bead is whirling around at a constant radius $R$, the only thing providing the centripetal force for this is the spring. Equate the two forces $$-mR\omega^2=-k(R-a)$$
and solve for $R$. As a check on the calculation, make sure that the result is greater than $a$.